# Mulitple occurance in a line - find first match only

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to learn regular expressions. How can  I find the first occurrence of the email address given line below:

```
'   for somebody@domain.com  for   somebody@domain.com '
```

I was trying with occurrences as shown below:

```
et=re.findall('for (<.+@.+>){1}?','   for somebody@domain.com  for   somebody@domain.com ')
```

but without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore strict email address validation which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) , you can use :

```
import re

pattern = r'\S+@\S+'
string = '   for somebody@domain.com  for   somebody@domain.com '

try:
    first_match = next(re.finditer(pattern, string))
    print(first_match.group())
except StopIteration:
    print('No match found')
```

click for [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LpePpm/1)

Comment: I thought that there will be no answer so i stopped tracking my own question.....